# How Would I Calculate this by Hand?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, algorithms

I know how to do summations and I know the equivalent equations for them. I am just lost on the second summation and how to proceed there. I have the wolfram alpha answer, I just need to know how do this by hand.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i}^{n+4} \sum_{k=3}^{j+7}1$$
I have the answer, but I want to know how to do it, or something similar in the future.

Comment: Work from inside out.  If what is being added repeatedly isn't changing according to index of the innermost summation, then use the naive definition of multiplication to see that $\underbrace{a+a+a+a+\dots+a}_{b~\text{times}}=a\times b$.  Use the linearity of summation to break things apart to handle separately, that is that $\sum_i(a_i+b_i)=\sum_i(a_i)+\sum_i(b_i)$, and then know your identities for $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i$ and $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i^2$ and so on.  Finally, it can help to remember $\sum\limits_{i=a}^bx_i = \sum\limits_{i=0}^bx_i - \sum\limits_{i=0}^{a-1} x_i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These concatenated sums need to be dealt with from the inside out. Firstly we deal with the easiest sum:
$$ \sum_{k=3}^{j+7} 1 = j + 5 $$
By linearity of finite sums we can also say:
$$ \sum j + 5 = \sum j + \sum 5 $$
And most importantly, we can say that:
$$ \sum_{j=i}^{n+4} = \sum_{j=1}^{n+4} - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} $$
Which we may apply to both pieces to obtain:
$$ \sum_{j=i}^{n+4} j + 5 = \frac{(n+4)(n+5)}{2} - \frac{i(i-1)}{2} + 5(n+4) - 5(i-1)$$
At this point it's just a matter of breaking the last sum into different pieces, and using the formula for the sum of squares to sum over $i^2$ where needed.